# How to call a method and its variable in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Trying to display the current date on a page in JSP but getting odd error codes. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
    <% Date today = new Date(); %>
<%! 
   public String displayDate(Date date){
       return date.toString(); 
   }
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><center>Today's Date is: <%displayDate(<%=today%>);%></center></h1>
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could share your "odd error codes" with us? Or are we supposed to guess what your error might be?

Answer (score 2):

This

```
<%displayDate(<%=today%>);%>
```

should be something like

```
<%= displayDate(today); %>
```

Also, I'd recommend you migrate away from scriptlets.